# Solr: type text versus string when indexed="false"

Tags: solr, schema, field

I have read solr documentation about [Field Type](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/field-type-definitions-and-properties.html).

- When a field is set to `indexed` = "true" it can be used in queries to retrieve documents. If not, field is not searchable, sortable or facetable.
- When the type of the field is defined as a text (`type` = "text)", the analysis, the tokenization is performed.

But I don't understand in schemas.xml what can be the meaning of a field like this:

```
<field name = "resume" type = "text_fr" indexed = "false" stored = "true" />
```

Shouldn't you put type = "string"? This would avoid an analysis and tokenization cost which is not used anyway?

Comment: One possible reason to use a `text` field (like `text_fr`) instead of a `string` field is that I believe there are certain limitations on the size of a `string` field, but `text` fields support much larger values.

Comment: The limitation is for the token size, not the stored content. When indexed is false, I'd guess sit wouldn't be relevant in either case.